# Find difference between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes *old_df* and *new_df* that I am reading from SQL Server database. They both contain data on various products and their prices. I need to compare these two dataframes and create table, that would look like this: (dummy data)

| Seller | Code | Product | Old_Price | New_Price | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MC | oTMFtAS8w6 | Golden Apple | 3360 | 3200 | Price change |
| MC | kYp2jkorw6 | washing machine |  | 765 | New Product |
| MC | UGl93h4qGo | outlet | 1155 |  | Product deleted |

I have come up with the solution that is really ineffective due to the last iterrows function:

```
def compare(old_df,new_df,sellers_list):
df_changes = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Seller' , 'Code', 'Product' , 'Old_Price', 'New_Price', 'Status'])

for seller in sellers_list:
    old_df[seller]['Concat'] = old_df[seller]['Code'] + old_df[seller]['Product']
    new_df[seller]['Concat'] = new_df[seller]['Code'] + new_df[seller]['Product']

    temp_df1 = old_df[seller].set_index('Concat')
    temp_df2 = new_df[seller].set_index('Concat')
    temp_df1 = temp_df1[['Seller','Product', 'Code' ,'Price']]
    temp_df2 = temp_df2[['Seller','Product', 'Code','Price']]
    
    df_concat = pd.concat([temp_df1,temp_df2], axis= 'columns', keys= ['Old', 'New']).drop_duplicates(keep= False)
    
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    final_df = final_df.append(df_concat[df_concat[('Old',    'Price')] != df_concat[('New', 'Price')]])

    for index, row in final_df.iterrows():
        if pd.isnull(row[('Old',    'Seller')]):
            df_changes = df_changes.append({'Seller' : row[('New',    'Seller')], 'Code' : row[('New',    'Code')], 'Product': row[('New',    'Product')] , 'Old_Price' : None, 'New_Price' : row[('New',    'Price')], 'Status': 'New Product'}, ignore_index= True)
        elif pd.isnull(row[('New',    'Seller')]):
            df_changes = df_changes.append({'Seller' : row[('Old',    'Seller')], 'Code' : row[('Old',    'Code')], 'Product': row[('Old',    'Product')] , 'Old_Price' : row[('Old',    'Price')], 'New_Price' : None , 'Status': 'Product discontinued'}, ignore_index= True)
        else:
            df_changes = df_changes.append({'Seller' : row[('New',    'Seller')], 'Code' : row[('New',    'Code')], 'Product': row[('New',    'Product')] , 'Old_Price' : row[('Old',    'Price')], 'New_Price' : row[('New',    'Price')], 'Status': 'Price change'}, ignore_index= True)
     

return df_changes
```

I am using concat as sometimes there is one Code for two Products (the difference is in the Product name).
Could you help me find a more effective solution to my problem?

Comment: can you be more descriptive, what difference are you expecting ?

Comment: The difference in price. At this time, I am concatenating two dataframes based on columns 'Concat' (Part_Code + Product). If old price is not same as new price, there has been some change. Final_df therefore contains only rows where old price and new price doesnt match. Last iterrows function checks what is that change. If there was price and now price is different, it creates row in df_changes with where status is Price change. If there was price and now there is not, status is "Product deleted" and if there wasn't price for this Concat, but in new df there is, the status is 'New Product"

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you provide sample data from both dataframes as well as an expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect case for `merge` and the `indicator` parameter:

Input data:

```
>>> df1  # old products
  Seller        Code       Product  Price
0     MC  oTMFtAS8w6  Golden Apple   3360
1     MC  UGl93h4qGo        outlet   1155

>>> df2  # new products
  Seller        Code          Product  Price
0     MC  oTMFtAS8w6     Golden Apple   3200
1     MC  kYp2jkorw6  washing machine    765
```

```
out = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Product', how='outer',
               suffixes=('', '_new'), indicator=True)

# Remove products where price has unchanged
out = out[out['Price'] !=  out['Price_new']]

out['Status'] = out['_merge'].replace({'both': 'Price change',
                                       'left_only': 'Product deleted',
                                       'right_only': 'New Product'})

out.update(out[['Seller', 'Seller_new', 'Code', 'Code_new']].bfill(axis=1))

out = out[['Seller', 'Code', 'Product', 'Price', 'Price_new', 'Status']]
```

Output result

```
>>> out
  Seller        Code          Product   Price  Price_new           Status
0     MC  oTMFtAS8w6     Golden Apple  3360.0     3200.0     Price change
1     MC  UGl93h4qGo           outlet  1155.0        NaN  Product deleted
2     MC  kYp2jkorw6  washing machine     NaN      765.0      New Product
```